# Change postgres default behavior for connection to database when dbname not supplied

Tags: postgresql

According to postgres documentation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-connect.html

> dbname
>   The database name. Defaults to be the same as the user name. In certain contexts, the value is checked for extended formats; see Section 33.1.1 for more details on those.

for instance, issuing the following command:

```
psql -U username -h 0.0.0.0 -c "SELECT * from some.table"
```

will automatically issue the command on a database named 'username' if that database exists.

Is there a way to change the default behavior to require an explicit database name rather than the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [same Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/libpq-envars.html)

> The following environment variables can be used to select default connection parameter values, which will be used by `PQconnectdb`, `PQsetdbLogin` and `PQsetdb` if no value is directly specified by the calling code[...]
>
> - `PGDATABASE` behaves the same as the **dbname** connection parameter.

If you want `psql` to fail if the database name is not explicitly given on the command line, set the variable `PGDATABASE` to point to a non-existent database, e.g. `export PGDATABASE=" "` or `export PGDATABASE=""`.

As to your question:

> whether or not the default behavior can be modified to not connect to a database named after the user if no database name is supplied either through an environment variable, or the `psql` command line utility.

we can find a definitive answer in the [libpq source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/interfaces/libpq/fe-connect.c):

```
/*
 * If database name was not given, default it to equal user name
 */
if (conn->dbName == NULL || conn->dbName[0] == '\0')
{
    if (conn->dbName)
        free(conn->dbName);
    conn->dbName = strdup(conn->pguser);
    if (!conn->dbName)
        goto oom_error;
}
```

The only way to modify the default behaviour is to edit the code fragment shown above and recompile the library.

Comment: Just to clarify though, I have yet to find anything that mentions whether or not the default behavior can be modified to not connect to a database named after the user if no database name is supplied either through an environment variable, or the psql command line utility.